# elasticsearch - Failed to load class with value s3 S3RepositoryModule after successfull cloud-aws plugin installation

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, snapshot

Using elasticsearch 1.6.1 rpm installation in a EC2 instance.
I have installed the cloud-aws plugin which backs up indices in s3, restarted the node, and apparently it went fine.

```
Installed elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws/2.6.1 into /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/cloud-aws
```

When I list the installed plugins, everything looks ok:

```
elasticsearch/bin/plugin --list
Installed plugins:
- cloud-aws
```

But when I try to create a snapshot through the API with the following PUT I get:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_s3_repository' -d '{
    "type": "s3",
    "settings": {
        "bucket": "elasticsearchbkp",
        "region": "sa-east-1"
    }
}'
```

Stacktrace:

> "error":"RemoteTransportException[[Whatever Name][inet[/10.1.1.1.1:9300]][cluster:admin/repository/put]];
>   nested: RepositoryException[[my_s3_repository] failed to create
>   repository]; nested: NoClassSettingsException[failed to load class
>   with value [s3]; tried [s3,
>   org.elasticsearch.repositories.S3RepositoryModule,
>   org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3RepositoryModule,
>   org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3RepositoryModule]]; nested:
>   ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.repositories.s3.S3RepositoryModule];
>   ",    "status":500 }

Weird thing is that I made it work with the elasticsearch-1.6.1.zip  version.
Content inside plugin and lib folders:

ls elasticsearch/lib/

```
antlr-runtime-3.5.jar           jna-4.1.0.jar                       lucene-grouping-4.10.4.jar     lucene-queryparser-4.10.4.jar
apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar  jts-1.13.jar                        lucene-highlighter-4.10.4.jar  lucene-sandbox-4.10.4.jar
asm-4.1.jar                     log4j-1.2.17.jar                    lucene-join-4.10.4.jar         lucene-spatial-4.10.4.jar
asm-commons-4.1.jar             lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.4.jar  lucene-memory-4.10.4.jar       lucene-suggest-4.10.4.jar
elasticsearch-1.6.1.jar         lucene-core-4.10.4.jar              lucene-misc-4.10.4.jar         sigar
groovy-all-2.4.4.jar            lucene-expressions-4.10.4.jar       lucene-queries-4.10.4.jar      spatial4j-0.4.1.jar
```

ls elasticsearch/plugins/cloud-aws/

```
aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.12.jar  aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.12.jar  elasticsearch-cloud-aws-2.6.1.jar  jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar  joda-time-2.8.2.jar
aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.10.12.jar   commons-codec-1.4.jar        httpclient-4.3.5.jar               jackson-core-2.5.3.jar
aws-java-sdk-kms-1.10.12.jar   commons-logging-1.1.3.jar    httpcore-4.3.2.jar                 jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar
```

Any ideas? THANKS =)

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_nodes/plugins`?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. Even though I was trying this plugin out in development, I was doing it at work, and there were like 3 or 4 other nodes joining my cluster, because we were all **using default cluster name "elasticsearch" within the network.**

And yes, if I had tried this -XGET /_nodes/plugins command before, I'd have figured it out way earlier. Thanks =)

So, my request to create a snapshot was being sent to a random node that didnt have the plugin installed.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!